# syntax highlighting in text area , flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, syntax, textarea, highlighting

My application requires users to type some code in the textarea. I wish to provide them the syntax highlighting and the tab interface. 
I did my homework but couldnt achieve it .

I observe the first tab is always displayed as a space in flex textarea. I wish to solve this problem also, in case the tab interface is successfully provided.

Any references or code help will be great

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been using [as3syntaxhighlight](http://code.google.com/p/as3syntaxhighlight/) which works pretty well, and was the only open source library I could find.  I was able to easily add custom keywords, and change coloring.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by tab interface?  You want like a list of possible words when you press tab?

I seriously recommend not doing that because it would mean hijacking the tab's normal behavior which is moving between components.  I would recommend you use another key(ctrl+space?) or a different kind of interface for it.  For the highlighting, just use Sean's suggestion.